# Why is _this.debug not a function in this test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I am developing a proof of concept for a project. I work with Node.js and express.js and I am trying to unit test this using jest.js. This is a simple API that returns a simple hardcoded message.

My intent is to test that debug logs the message "Health check" when the route is called.

I am having a problem with the following unit test (I know there are no assertion in my test, that was going to be the next step once the test passes):

FAIL  app/tests/server/routes/health-check/HealthCheck.test.js (24.196 s)

● Feature #1: Logging health check request › whenRouting_thenDebugShouldSendTheRouteMessage

```
TypeError: _this.debug is not a function

   7 |         this.router = router;
   8 |         this.route = (request, response) => {
>  9 |             this.debug('Health check');
     |                  ^
  10 |             response.send({"Health check": "Passed!"});
  11 |         }
  12 |     }

  at HealthCheck.route (app/server/routes/health-check/HealthCheck.js:9:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/tests/server/routes/health-check/HealthCheck.test.js:35:21)
```

I suspect `debug` is not bound to the test instance. How should I go about to solve this issue?

Also when I run the code everything work fine.

Here is my test class:

```
import HealthCheck, {ROUTE_NAME} from "../../../../server/routes/health-check/HealthCheck";
import debug from 'debug';
import express from "express";

jest.mock('debug');

const extendMock = jest.fn();
const requestMock = jest.fn();
const responseMock = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
        send: jest.fn()
    };
});


debug.extend = extendMock;

let healthCheck;

describe('Feature #1: Logging health check request', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setup();
    });

    test('whenBuildingRoute_thenDebugShouldExtendWithTheRouteName', () => {
        expect(debug.extend.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(ROUTE_NAME);
    });

    test('whenCreatingRoute_thenTheRouterShouldBeReturned', () => {
        let router = healthCheck.create();
        expect(router).toBe(express);
    });

    test('whenRouting_thenDebugShouldSendTheRouteMessage', () => {
        healthCheck.route(requestMock, responseMock);
    });

});

function setup() {
    express.mockClear();
    debug.mockClear();
    extendMock.mockClear();
    requestMock.mockClear();
    responseMock.mockClear();

    healthCheck = new HealthCheck(express, debug);
}
```

Here is the class I am trying to test:

```
export const ROUTE_PATH = "/health-check";
export const ROUTE_NAME = "health-check";

export default class HealthCheck {
    constructor(router, debug) {
        this.debug = debug.extend(ROUTE_NAME);
        this.router = router;
        this.route = (request, response) => {
            this.debug('Health check');
            response.send({"Health check": "Passed!"});
        }
    }

    create() {
        this.router.get(ROUTE_PATH, this.route);
        return this.router;
    }
}
```

Also here is a test class that I already have where all the tests are passing and I don't understand what is different.

```
import LoggingMiddleware, {
    BUILDING_MIDDLEWARE_MESSAGE, HTTP_REQUEST_MESSAGE,
    MIDDLEWARE_NAME
} from "../../../server/middlewares/LoggingMiddleware";
import express from 'express';
import debug from 'debug';
import {expressMockListen, expressMockUse} from "../../../../__mocks__/express";

jest.mock('debug');

const REQUEST_METHOD = "A method";

const requestMock = jest.fn(()=>{
    return {
        method: REQUEST_METHOD,
        path: jest.fn(),
        headers: jest.fn(),
        query: jest.fn(),
        body: jest.fn()
    }
});
const responseMock = jest.fn();
const nextMock = jest.fn();

let loggingMiddleware;

describe('Feature #1: Logging HTTP requests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        setup();
    });

    test('whenBuildingAMiddleware_thenTheLoggerShouldDebugAMessage', () => {
        expect(debug.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(BUILDING_MIDDLEWARE_MESSAGE);
    });

    test('whenGettingName_thenTheNameShouldBeReturned', () => {
        expect(loggingMiddleware.getName()).toBe(MIDDLEWARE_NAME);
    });

    test('whenGettingTheMiddlewareFunction_thenExpressUseShouldBeCalled', () => {
        loggingMiddleware.getMiddlewareFunction();
        expect(expressMockUse).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    test('whenGettingTheMiddlewareFunction_thenExpressRouterShouldBeReturned', () => {
        const router = loggingMiddleware.getMiddlewareFunction();
        expect(router).toBe(express);
    });

    test('whenLogging_thenNextShouldBeCalled', () => {
        loggingMiddleware.log(requestMock, responseMock, nextMock);
        expect(nextMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    test('whenLogging_thenTheMessageShouldBeLogged', () => {
        loggingMiddleware.log(requestMock, responseMock, nextMock);
        expect(debug.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe(HTTP_REQUEST_MESSAGE);
    });
});

function setup() {
    express.mockClear();
    expressMockUse.mockClear();
    expressMockListen.mockClear();
    debug.mockClear();

    requestMock.mockClear();
    responseMock.mockClear();
    nextMock.mockClear();

    loggingMiddleware = new LoggingMiddleware(express, debug);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extendMock` is a stub, so it's expected that mocked `debug.extend` returns `undefined` instead of a function.

In case a module needs more specific mocks, auto-mock needs to be replaced with manual mock. A function that `debug.extend` can be exposed through exports in order to be accessed directly in tests:

```
import debug, { mockDebugInstance } from 'debug';

jest.mock('debug', () => {
  const mockDebugInstance = jest.fn();
  const mockDebug = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    extend: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockDebugInstance);
  };

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: mockDebug,
    mockDebugInstance
  };
});

...

expect(debug.extend).toBeCalledWith(...);
expect(mockDebugInstance).toBeCalledWith(...);
```